# Mapping a Boolean function over a list

Tags: python

I'm new to programming so this is probably a silly question!

I'm trying to write a function that takes a list of letter grades and returns a Boolean true or false depending on whether it is a passing grade

```
## Calculate total units passed

def unitPassed(letterGrade):
    if letterGrade == 'N':
        passed = False
    else:
        if letterGrade == 'NCN':
           passed = False
        else:
            if letterGrade == 'WN':
                passed = False
            else:
                True
    return passed

unitsPassed = map(unitPassed,courseGradeLetter)
```

I've attempted to do this by creating a function that tests if a grade is a passing grade, and then map this over a list of grade.

The problem is that I get the following error for a list that contains more than one element:

```
local variable 'passed' referenced before assignment
```

If I try it with a list containing one element I get the correct result.

Any ideas why this is?

Thanks.

--

Thanks everyone, your answers have helped me a lot!

Comment: Try with `passed = True` line 13.

Comment: Ah, it works now. silly mistake - thanks!

Comment: A side note: the whole function can be rewritten as the single line `return letterGrade not in ('N', 'NCN', 'WN')`

Comment: `list(map(lambda l: l not in ('N', 'NCN', 'WN'), courseGradeLetter))` or `[l not in ('N', 'NCN', 'WN') for l in courseGradeLetter]`

Comment: I am flagging this post as "off-topic", because the error was produced by a simple typographical mistake and is not likely to help future readers.

Comment: You have just to intilize your boolean passed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some have already pointed your error and posted the most pythonic solutions, but anyway - here's another code review, but this time a step by step one:

First point: learn to use `elif` instead of nesting `if` clauses in `else` clauses:

```
def unitPassed(letterGrade):
    if letterGrade == 'N':
        passed = False
    elif letterGrade == 'NCN':
        passed = False
    elif letterGrade == 'WN':
        passed = False
    else:
        passed = True
    return passed
```

As you can see this is already more readable.

Second point: in Python we favor "early returns" - ie, in this kind of tests, instead of setting a variable in all branches and returning it at the end, we return directly (which avoids `elif`/`else` chains etc):

```
def unitPassed(letterGrade):
    if letterGrade == 'N':
        return False
    if letterGrade == 'NCN':
        return False
    if letterGrade == 'WN':
        return False
    return True
```

Which makes the code even more straightforward.

And of course the last refactoring is to avoid the multiple tests when possible, as posted by Dadep and digitake (but using a tuple instead of a list because we dont need the overhead of a list here):

```
def unitPassed(letterGrade):
    return letterGrade not in ("N", "NCN", "WN")
```

Also, you are using `map()` in your code snippet but while `map()` is still perfectly valid and appropriate, the more idiomatic (and marginally faster) version here would be a list comprehension:

```
passed = [unitPassed(letter) for letter in courseGradeLetter]
```

And since `unitPassed` is now basically a simple short expression, you can just inline it (unless  of course you need this function elsewhere):

```
passed = [letter not in ('N', 'NCN', 'NWN') for letter in courseGradeLetter]
```

Comment: Your `unitPassed` needs to use `not in`, ditto the list comp

Answer (score 2):

how about this

```
def unitPassed(letterGrade):
    return letterGrade not in ['N', 'NCN', 'WN']

unitsPassed = map(unitPassed,courseGradeLetter)
```

Comment: `return letterGrade in ['N', 'NCN', 'WN']:` should be `return letterGrade not in ['N', 'NCN', 'WN']` (the column shouldn't be there and if the grade is IN the list then you should return `False` I believe.)

Comment: @Deuce thanks. that's exactly what i had in mind. but my finger just disobeyed me.

Answer (score 0):

you can redefine your function as :

```
>>> def unitPassed(letterGrade):
...     GP=['N', 'NCN', 'WN']
...     if letterGrade in GP:
...         return False
...     return True
... 
>>> letterGrade='DE'
>>> unitPassed(letterGrade)
True
>>> letterGrade='NCN'
>>> unitPassed(letterGrade)
False
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is in the 3rd else statement, i.e. in line 13.
Change `True` to `passed = True`
Also, you can make your function clean,

```
def unitPassed(letterGrade):
    if letterGrade == 'N':
        passed = False
    elif letterGrade == 'NCN':
        passed = False
    elif letterGrade == 'WN':
        passed = False
    else:
        passed = True
    return passed
```

Comment: this isn't properly indented, nor is it a particularly concise way of doing this.

Comment: He is new to programming so I just told how to write if else statements in a clean way. There are many other ways to do it, but he wants to find the error in "his" code.